# What is the jQuery method to detect when audio has stopped playing?

Tags: jquery

I want to toggle a function when the audio is done being played.

Here's the code I tried(without luck):

```
$(function(){
  if ($('#audio').get(0).stopped == true) {
  $('div#switch').toggle(); 
  } 
});
```

Comment: Which audio player are you using?

Comment: HTML5 audio: <audio id="audio">
  <source src="audio/..." type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="..." type="audio/mpeg" />
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

Answer (score 0):

why don't u try some nice HTML5 audio libraries which has events handlers (stop event, playing event and etc).

One of the easiest library i came across is http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/

Hope this helps. Happy coding.